# Get Azure AD Access Token from a .NET framework 2.0 ASP.NET app using WebClient or similar method

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory

Is there a way to get Get Azure AD Access Token from a .NET framework 2.0 ASP.NET application using WebClient or similar method? I have tried to refer AADL from nuget but due to framework version we are unable to refer.

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory

is above library available for .NET framework 2.0

Comment: All Azure services work with HTTP APIs, so the answer is yes. On the other hand .NET Framework 2.0 went out of support several years ago and probably *can't* connect to *ANY* Azure service simply because it didn't support TLS1.2. If I remember correctly, Azure (and the other cloud providers) require TLS1.2 for a couple of years now.

Comment: This means you *have* to run on top of a .NET 4.0 runtime at least, so why not just use the *correct* runtime version in the project? The oldest supported .NET version is 4.5.2, with 4.6 using TLS1.2 by default

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Thank you for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is above library available for .NET framework 2.0

The answer is no.

> Is there a way to get Get Azure AD Access Token from a .NET framework
>   2.0 ASP.NET application using WebClient or similar method?

The answer is yes. Just like @ Panagiotis Kanavos said, all Azure services work with HTTP APIs.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow